# How do I create a LAMP server via EC2 Image Builder?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I am trying to set up a resilient way to deploy our monolithic web app on an AWS EC2.  My current setup uses Ansible to "manually" install the components for a LAMP server on the latest Amazon-Managed Ubuntu AMI.

I recently discovered **AWS EC2 Image Builder**, which seems like it could be used to create an AMI with Apache, MySQL (client), and PHP.

In my AWS Console, I went through these steps:

1. EC2 Image Builder >
2. Image pipelines >
3. Create image pipeline >
4. Create Recipe >
5. Image Type: AMI >
6. Source Image: [Amazon Linux | Ubuntu | CentOS | Redhat | Suse ]   (I tried each one)

After the above 6 steps, when trying to add an (Amazon Managed) Component, I see PHP 7.1 ~ 7.3.. can be added.   But I do NOT see what I would think are other basic components:  Apache, Ngnix, MySQL..

How do I add Apache2 + MySQL (client) + PHP to an Amazon managed Ubuntu box via EC2 Image Builder?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create build components and define a custom installation process.

Click the 'Create Build Component' button in the 'Components' section of the 'Recipe' page. Scroll down to 'Definition' and select 'Use example' to see how it works.